# Ruby: substitute all references in part of a string

Tags: ruby, regex, substring

I want to substitute all references of `.` to `_` in parts of a given string inside a `%{}`. See this example:

```
'example 1.1 %{a.b.c} of {d.e.f}.'
```

should be replaced to

```
'example 1.1 %{a_b_c} of {d_e_f}.'
```

I have to do this because on older ruby `example %{a.b.c}' % {:'a.b.c' => 'result'}` doesn't work.

Comment: What part of your code is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gsub with a block:

```
data = 'example 1.1 %{a.b.c} of {d.e.f}.'
p data.gsub(/{.+?}/){|x| x.gsub('.','_')} #=> "example 1.1 %{a_b_c} of {d_e_f}."
```

Comment: Ok, do you refer the the entire problem or just the second gsub? In any case, why is tr better?

Comment: The second. Because it is faster.

Answer (score 3):

As @sawa suggested, a little tweak:

```
'example 1.1 %{a.b.c} of {d.e.f}.'.gsub(/{.+?}/) { |s| s.tr '.', '_' }
=> "example 1.1 %{a_b_c} of {d_e_f}."
```